# Quitting application in Android

Tags: android

I want to quit application in Android. Just put a "quit" button, which kills my app.

I know I shouldn't do this. I know that this is not the philosophy of the OS.

If you know how it can be done, pls share.

In the app, I have many opened activities, so "finish()" will not do the job.

Thank you for your information in advance.
Danail

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your answer helped me, Pentium10, but I needed to do one more thing :

I had to clear(close) all my previous activities with

> Intent i = new Intent();
>
> i.setClass(this, FirstActivity.class);
>
> i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
>
> startActivity(i);

This means: every activity, started after FirstActivity, is closed. (In other words, this cleans the activity stack above FirstActivity). Then all I have to do is finish my FirstActivity.

Answer (score 6):

Way One

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())
```

Way Two

```
System.exit(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Close all the previous activities as follows:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("Exit me", true);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
```

Then in MainActivity onCreate() method add this to finish the MainActivity

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    if( getIntent().getBooleanExtra("Exit me", false)){
        finish();
        return; // add this to prevent from doing unnecessary stuffs
    }
```